# Find the number and percentage of occurance in Python

Tags: python, file-io, counter

I have a very big file like in GB and it has 4 columns. From that i have to find the number of occurrences of first 2 columns.

```
Col[1] Col[2] Col[3] Col[4]
```

So here i have to consider the pairs from `Col[1] and Col[2]`

I have to find the number of occurrences of that particular pair in entire file

Eg:

```
Col[1] Col[2]
1234   5678
8901   3456
1234   5678
0987   2345
1234   5678
```

So we see that `1234 5678` has occurred 3 times so far.

I did refer some code from another post here and tried to implement with my data file and find some errors.

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter
import ast

 def collect_pairs('FileName.txt'):

    pair_counter = Counter()
    for line in open('FileName.txt'):
      unique_tokens = sorted(set(ast.literal_eval(lines)))
      combos = combination(unique_token, 2)
      pair_counter += Counter(combos)
    return pair_counter
    outfile = open('Outputfile.txt', 'w')
    p = collect_pairs(outfile)
    print p.most_common(10)
```

Comment: ...what errors?! Please edit the question to provide full traceback.

Comment: Why are you using `ast.literal_eval`? Are you just copying code you found without knowing what it does?

Comment: def collect_pairs('FileName.txt'): Invalid sysntax

Comment: Does the line 1234 0000 5678 0000 count?

Comment: @interjay yes for now i just copied the code and i am trying to understand how that works. I am trying to edit the code according to my requirement. It is throwing more errors. Mostly syntax errors.

Comment: @Phani.lav well yes, that isn't valid syntax. Perhaps try reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: @timgeb you mean the first row ?? Yes it does count.

Comment: @Phani.lav I mean that you have 4 columns and my question is whether your pair of number must occur in the first two column, or may occur in any column.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i also tried infile = open('file.txt', 'r') and then def collect_pair(infile). Both show same error.

Comment: @timgeb they are definitely in first 2 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a `defaultdict` and reading the file line by line.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

# get number of occurences for the first two columns
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    f.readline() # discard the header line
    for numlines, line in enumerate(f,1):
        line = line.strip().split()
        c = line[0], line[1]
        d[c] += 1

# compute 100*(occurences/numlines) for each key in d
d = {k:(v, 100*float(v)/numlines) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
for k in d:
    print k, d[k]
```

For your sample file, this will print:

```
('0987', '2345') (1, 20.0)
('8901', '3456') (1, 20.0)
('1234', '5678') (3, 60.0)
```

where the format is `(column1, column2) (occurrences, percentage)`.

If you just need the occurrences for a single pair, e.g. '1234' and '5678', you can do it like this:

```
find = '1234', '5678'
counter = 0
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    f.readline() # discard the header line
    for numlines, line in enumerate(f,1):
        line = line.strip().split()
        c = line[0], line[1]
        if c == find:
            counter += 1

print counter, 100*float(counter)/numlines
```

Output for your sample file:

```
3 60.0
```

I have always assumed that the headerline does not count when computing the percentage-value. If it does count, change `enumerate(f,1)` to `enumerate(f,2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much..I will try this code soon and reply back here.

Comment: @Phani.lav no problem. Another thing: If your file does not have a headerline, i.e. does not start with the line "Col[1] Col[2] ... ", then delete the `f.readline()` from the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works like charm :) so can we also find the ratio between these occurrences?

Comment: While displaying on terminal this works great. When i am trying to redirect the output to a file it is only writing 1 row i have included the following two lines in the code.                     with open('filename.txt', 'w') as outfile: (in top just after the read with) and outfile.write("%s %s\n" % (k, d[k]))
in the for loop at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much .. everything works great. Thr is no header line in specific. I can have a output file with the results. Now i have to find the ratio of occurrences. Do i have to pose a new question here ??

Comment: You can post a new question and include the dictionary you already have.

Comment: I have a small query regarding the output generated it comes with () , and ''. I have to remove them. Is there any way?? Please do suggest

Comment: I have request to make i am stuck with finding the neighbors and the count of neighbors for each pair of nodes. I read it from a file. I did post that question i got down voted and blocked for too broad question. could you please help with that too. I did follow the tutorial with networkx ..but seems i am doing something wrong.